# How add/push data in nested array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

This is my collection in mongoAltas:

---

```
{
    "_id":{"$oid":"5ff35fefa0652d23c637bf51"},
    "plantId":"3",
    "status":"SUCCESS",
    "healthMonitor":[{"PlantName":""}]
}
```

---

When I am trying to insert any data to the nested array "PlantName", the document is not updated and returns null. I tried `$push` and `$set` and tried `find_one_and_update` and just `update_one` but both does not work

Here is the update I tried:

```
collection.find_one_and_update({'plantId':3}, 
                        {  '$push': {
                            "healthMonitor.$.PlantName": "Herb"
                                }
                        })

collection.find_one_and_update({'plantId':3}, 
                        {  '$push': {
                            "healthMonitor":[{PlantName": "Herb"}]
                                }
                        })
```

If any one know how the code works for nested document please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PlantName` is not a "nested array". `healthMonitor` is an array that contains a single item, which is an object containing one field: `PlantName`.

Your update is not working as your data is string `"3"` but your update filter is on numeric `3`.

If you want to update the `PlantName` field in the first element of the array, use:

```
collection.update_one({'plantId': '3'}, {'$set': {'healthMonitor.0.PlantName': 'Herb'}})
```

Comment: This worked for updating the array Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to insert new data object inside an array of an object of an exsisting document record below code can be used:

```
collection.update_one({'plantId':'3'}, {'$push': {'healthMonitor':
                                                       {'PlantName': 'tomato'}}})
```